# How to store mail in my computer when downloading by email client?

Tags: c#, email, linq-to-xml, imap, gmail-imap

In my project "email client"When i download mail can i save mail by xml? or others type? which is better?

Comment: You're going to need to clarify what you're trying to do and what criteria are important to you.  Better in what terms?  Speed?  Disk space?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you use SMTP, POP or IMAP, the electronic mail is transferred in text format defined by [RFC-5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322).

A simple solution would be to store the emails as individual text files. If you use the `.eml` extension, many email clients (Outlook Express, Mozilla Thunderbird, &c.) will recognise these files and will be able to open them without further processing.

Comment: How to use and create .msg in C#?

Comment: @Sếp Đậu: `.eml` files (I originally put `.msg` which is incorrect) are simply text files. The mail headers appear first as key-value pairs separated with ': ' and the body follows, after a blank line, as text with attachments MIME encoded. How you produce these will depend upon which library you are using to download these and the facilities it provides.